# Linux Shell Script, $@ does not work with alias

Tags: linux, shell

Here is my script named *t.sh*:

```
#! /bin/sh
alias hls='ls -h'
shopt -s expand_aliases
hls /           # try 1
$@              # try2
```

When I try running the script as:

```
./t.sh hls /
```

The *"try 1"* line works well, but the *"try 2"* line does not work, which reports error `hls: command not found`.

Anybody know the reason and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use an alias like a function.  functions set and can use $@.  Aliases can only use the $@ from the invoking process which is almost never what you want.

Comment: @EdGrimm: No, he wants to expand the `$@` into `hls /`, and have _that_ be executed. OP is _not_ using alias as a function, it really is alias, it's just that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

> Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed.

On the other hand, interpreting `$@` is "parameter expansion", and as all expansions, it is a part of executing a simple command. By that time, alias expansion time is over.

This will do what you want:

```
eval "$@"
```

Comment: @Zibo, Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)